Disable ring-bell on specific actions
I would like to use ring-bell which helps me while using emacs. But I don't want the ring-bell to activate on few actions like C-g or esc and more.
How can I do that?

You can customize the ring-bell to only be enabled in specific modes using below config
(defun my-bell-function ()
  (unless (memq this-command
        '(isearch-abort abort-recursive-edit exit-minibuffer
              keyboard-quit mwheel-scroll down up next-line previous-line
              backward-char forward-char))
    (ding)))
(setq ring-bell-function 'my-bell-function)

This code is reference from this stack-overflow answer.
